# When you 'Add from existing site columns' and then edit the subsequent list or library column's values - does it alter the original site column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, sharepoint-list

Just want to make sure, as it is not specifically mentioned in the:

`Add an existing site column to a list or library`

section of the Microsoft article [Create a column in a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2).

**Part 01**

If you did the following steps:

1. Go to `List` or `Library` settings page
2. Click `Add from existing site columns`
3. Select a `site` column and click `OK`
4. Click on the new `list` column name and change any of the fields, eg:
5. Name, Description, any options, Managed Metadata `Term Set Settings` etc
6. and click `OK`

Will that modify either:

1. The original `site` column?
2. Any other list or library columns that were 'added from existing site column'?
3. In the case of Managed Metadata columns, any of the associated Term Store values?

I am guessing the answer is:

> No, when you `Add from existing site columns` you are creating a `downstream` copy of the original site column and no changes you make to that `downstream` copy will go `upstream` to the original site column (or any other 'descendants' of that site column).

**Part 02**

It would be prudent to also understand exactly what the effect of editing the original `Site Column` has on `downstream` columns that were created from it.

For example:

1. What happens if you change a `Site Column`'s:
2. Name, Description, any options, Managed Metadata `Term Set Settings` etc
3. Will these changes be applied to all columns that were created from it?

Answer (score 2):

**Part 01**

Will that modify either:

The original site column? **No**
Any other list or library columns that were 'added from existing site column'? **No**
In the case of Managed Metadata columns, any of the associated Term Store values? **No**

Your understanding is totally right.

**Part 02**

It depends on if you set **Update Lists** to Yes. All lists using this site column should be updated with the settings on Edit site column page if you set it to Yes and sholudn't be updated if set to No.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post is quite thorough and communicated well:

[Editing and deleting site columns](https://learningshub.blog/2019/08/15/editing-and-deleting-site-columns)

Hopefully it is still accurate, it is dated 15/08/2019.

My understanding is that I *think* it comes down to which option you select in the `Update Lists` field shown below when you are `Editing` a `Site Column`:

[image]

To test this, I created a test `Site Column`, and when `Yes` is selected in the `Update Lists` field, and I make a change, I receive this prompt:

[image]

If I then select `OK`, I can see changes are applied to a 'descendant' list.

If however, I select `No` in the `Update Lists` field, and I make a change to the `Site Column`, I receive no prompt and no changes are made to 'descendant' lists.

*To be confirmed...*

It seems to me that selecting `No` in the `Update Lists` field and then saving a change *does not* 'break' the relationship between the `Site Column` and 'descendant' column (it's just that that *particular* change won't be applied to 'descendant' columns), because if I then make another change to the `Site Column`, and select `Yes` in the `Update Lists` field, and click `OK` when prompted, the changes *are* applied to the descendant list.

Conversely, the blog post above seems to infer that the relationship *will* be permanently broken:

> If “No” is selected, then in that case, it will not update every instance of this site column and now, *every list that has added this site column will lose all the references and get converted into List columns*

So that is the only disparity I can see between my understandings and those communicated in the blog post - I am not sure which is authoritatively correct.